# Voting Probability (Bayes Theorem)

Tags: probability, solution-verification

In a certain city, 30% of the people are conservatives, 50% are liberals, and 20% are independents.  Records show that in a particular election, 65% of the conservatives voted, 82% of the liberals voted, and 50% of the independents voted. If a person in the city is selected at random and it is learned that she did not vote in the last election, what is the probability that she is a Liberal?

30% = conservatives,  65% voted,  15% did not
50% = liberals, 82% voted, 18% did not
20% = independents, 50% voted, 50% did not

$(0.3)(0.15)+(0.5)(0.18)+(0.2)(0.5)=
0.045+0.09+0.1
=0.235$ did not vote

B = she is a liberal
A = she didn't vote

$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap \!\,B)}{P(A)}$
$=\frac{P(B)P(A|B)}{P(A)}$
$=\frac{(0.5)(0.18)}{0.235}$
$=\frac{0.09}{0.235}$
$=0.38$

Does this look correct?

Comment: $\frac{0.5\cdot(1-0.82)}{0.3\cdot(1-0.65)+0.5\cdot(1-0.82)+0.2\cdot(1-0.5)}$

Comment: Female and male political membership patterns and voting patterns differ. It should have said the person didn't vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\color{green}{\checkmark}$ Yes.   The theory, formulas, and algebra all seem to check out.

---

**Update:**

However, there was one misstep in fetching the data.

> $30\%$ = conservatives, $65\%$ voted, $\require{cancel}\cancelto{35}{15}\%$ did not $50\%$ = liberals, $82\%$ voted, $18\%$ did not $20\%$ = independents, $50\%$ voted, $50\%$ did not.

Comment: There was a miss-calculation for $P(A)$

Comment: Opps.  Yes.  @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins

Comment: Only reason I noticed was because I had this as a homework problem. I figured since this question has been viewed 6000 times that I’d point it out just in case I guess

Answer (score 1):

The percentage of conservatives that don't vote is 35%, not 15%, so your divisor should be 0.295 rather than 0.235, which means the answer should be 0.3051.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are 100,000 people in the city. "30% of the people are conservatives, 50% are liberals, and 20% are independents."  So there are 30,000 conservatives, 50,000 liberals, and 20,000 independents.

"Records show that in a particular election, 65% of the conservatives voted, 82% of the liberals voted, and 50% of the independents voted"  So .65(30,000)= 19,500 conservatives voted and 30,000- 19,500= 10,500 did not; .82(50,000)= 41,000 liberals voted and 50,000- 41,000= 9,000 did not; .50(20,000)= 10,000 independents voted and 10,000 did not.

"If a person in the city is selected at random and it is learned that she did not vote in the last election, what is the probability that she is a Liberal?"
  A total of 10,500+ 9,000+ 10,000= 29,500 people did not vote and 9,000 of those are liberals.  Given that a person did not vote the probability that she is a liberal is 9,000/29,500= 0.3051 or about 30%.